# How to hide ng-click attribute in dom

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angular script. I am trying to learn, and I am stuck in a place where i want to call a click event but condition is not want to use ng-click="myFunction()". Actually I want to hide which function is calling

```
<input type="button" id="employeeSubmit" value="Create"
       ng-click="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Please suggest me a way to handle this condition. 
thanks

Comment: why do you want to hide it?

Comment: Since js is a client-side language, you cannot hide anything, you could uglify your code to make it harder to read, but it would anyway be downloaded, readed and executed by user's browser. Anyone could see it

Comment: I want to do work like jQuery. in which we call it by id attribute and we not show onclick attribute on that element

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can call it only in your js.. with angular but also jquery or vanilla js ..

something like :

```
angular.element("#employeeSubmit").click(function(ev){

console.log('cliked from js');

});
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, if you're using Angular, you'll want to use ng-click instead of the html attribute onclick. You can update ng-click to run whatever function you want, so you won't need to hide it.

If you do want to remove the function that ng-click is calling, an option is to use JavaScript to remove it:

```
$("#test").attr("ng-click","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it in two seperate state using ng-switch or ngIf, then view as per your need 

`<input type="button" id="employeeSubmit" value="Create"
       ng-click="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default" />`

`<input type="button" id="employeeSubmit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help you:

```
$scope.condition=true;
    <button  ng-click=" !condition?myFunction():''">button</button> //example 1
    <button  ng-click="myFunction()" ng-disabled="condition" >button</button> //example 2
```